# Using high side switch when using boost converter

Tags: mosfet

I am using TI TPS613221A boost converter with fixed 3.3V output to power ESP8266. First i used high side switch (using Ap2411 IC) to turn ESP 3.3V on and off. Then i added P-MOSFET to turn the boost converter voltage on and off. So, my question is whether i should keep the high switch as kind of an isolator, or just drop it?

[image]

[image]